# Thunderbolt SSD hot plug failure on Intel NUC11TNBi7 with Ubuntu 20.04.3 (kernel 5.13)

Tags: ssd, thunderbolt, hotplug

we're having problems with hot plugging of thunderbolt SSDs with the Intel NUC11TNBi7. Operating system is Ubuntu 20.04.3 (Kernel 5.13) with latest BIOS version (0062).
If the system is booted with the thunderbolt SSD connected, it works as normal - the SSD mounts correctly and can be accessed.
However, if the thunderbolt SSD is connected after the system has booted, the whole system freezes for ~5 seconds and the SSD fails to connect. The following dmesg output occurs:

```
[   52.668997] nvme nvme0: pci function 0000:2e:00.0
[   52.669012] nvme 0000:2e:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   52.669203] nvme nvme0: Removing after probe failure status: -19
[   56.551753] usb usb2-port2: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[   56.551779] usb usb2-port2: unable to enumerate USB device
[   60.138303] thunderbolt 1-1: new device found, vendor=0x175 device=0x4000
[   60.138311] thunderbolt 1-1: SAMSUNG ELECTRONICS CO., LTD Portable SSD X5
```

We have tried different thunderbolt cables and different thunderbolt SSDs - exactly the same problem. Note: the issue is slightly intermittent, about 1 out of 10 times it does manage to connect.
We encountered the same issue with earlier Ubuntu 20.04 versions (20.04/20.04.2 kernel 5.4 and 5.11). All thunderbolt cables and SSDs function correctly including hot plugging on other thunderbolt equipped PCs/Macs. SSDs tested include 'Samsung Portable SSD X5'

Thanks,
Russell